# How to get Exchange 2013's Junk Email filter to honor the SCL set in a transport rule?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I'm having an external spam filter scan our messages for SPAM.  However, if the message is borderline SPAM, I'd love for it to be dropped into the user's "Junk Email" folder in Outlook/OWA.

I've setup the Antispam agents in Exchange 2013, but disabled most of the components.  I do however, have the org-wide SCLJunkTheshold set to 4.  I have a transport rule that is setting these borderline messages' SCL to 5.  However, they're not getting placed in the Junk Email folder.  I have verified in the headers that the SCL has been set correctly.  Any idea what else I should try?

Answer (score 0):

Well, eventually I got it to work.  However, when testing from my gmail account, sending emails in that should have been placed in the junk email folder.  It looks at some point in my testing it should have worked, but my gmail account was on the safe senders list.  I haven't really used the junk email filter in Outlook before so I didn't realize this.  I only noticed after seeing the header: "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Antispam-Report: SenderOnRecipientSafeSendersList"